# MaxStepSize, MaxSteps seem to have no effect on NDSolve in MATHEMATICA

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am a novice at mathematica so please bear with me!

I am trying to solve a nonlinear PDE in mma using NDSolve. The solution process is cut short because of singularities occurring much before the time for the simulation runs out. I realize that stiff systems that possess such singularities can be dealt with (at least by brute force) by reducing step size.

However "MaxSteps" or "MaxStepSize" doesn't seem to have a tangible effect on my code.

What gives? Any other method that I might be missing?

**

### CODE:

**

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq4, EvapThickFilm, h, S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]
Eq4[h_, {S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]h\) + 
    Div[-h^3 G Grad[h] + 
      h^3 S Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (VR E1^2 h^3)/(D1 (h + K1)^3)
        Grad[h] + M (h/(1 + h))^2 Grad[h]] + E1/(
    h + K1) + (R/6) D[D[(h^2/(1 + h)), x] h^3, x] == 0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
EvapThickFilm[S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_] := 
  Eq4[h[x, y, t], {S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R}];
TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]];



L = 318; TMax = 7.0;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
Kvar[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{0.01, t <= 4}, {0.05, t > 4}}]
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol = h /. NDSolve[{
     (*S,G,E,K,D,VR,M*)

     EvapThickFilm[1, 3, 0.1, Kvar[t], 0.01, 0.1, 0, 160],
     h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t],
     h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
     (*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)
     h[x, y, 0] == 
      1 + (-0.25 Cos[2 \[Pi] x/L] - 0.25 Sin[2 \[Pi] x/L]) Cos[
         2 \[Pi] y/L]
     },
    h,
    {x, 0, L},
    {y, 0, L},
    {t, 0, TMax}
    ][[1]]
```

### Error message:

NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.366570254802048`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

NDSolve::eerr: Warning: Scaled local spatial error estimate of 571455.5042645375`at t = 2.366570254802048` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 19 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or you may want to specify a smaller grid spacing using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options. >>

Comment: Usually, the shorter and more to the point your posted code is, the better answers you'll get

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making TMax in your code smaller, say 2 or 1.

This will remove the error. I found that if I solve using smaller time span, I can get away with even more accurate result (higher `AccuracyGoal ->`) and I can also use `MaxSteps -> Infinity`.

The trick is that the starting time of your current NDSolve call, does NOT have to be the same as initial conditions time. The starting time can be much removed away from initial conditions.

From help

```
The point Subscript[x, 0] that appears in the initial or boundary conditions 
need not lie in the range Subscript[x, min] to Subscript[x, max] over which 
the solution is sought.
```

This way, one can call NDSolve many more times, each for smaller time span, while all the time using the same initial conditions on each call. But in exchange, each step made, can be made more accurate. I found that calling NDSolve is very fast, and has no effect I could see on performance.

i.e. change NDSolve time specifications to be  `{from,to}`  vs `{0,TMax}`, where `from` and `to` are both advanced in smaller values each time, such that the distance between them remains small. (You need to add small logic code to do this), until you have covered the overall time range you were interested in solving over.

So, try changing your solver to solve for smaller steps, and I think you'll get much better results.

Also, try using `Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}` in your options for NDSolver, as Mathematica says it is stiff system.

Comment: Those are some really useful and interesting thoughts. I will implement them and post the results as a comment or a follow up. Thank you for the detailed reply!

Comment: @DNA, the above is how I do all the my simulations now. The idea again, is to replace ONE Interpolating function, which covers the WHOLE region, with many smaller ones, each covers smaller part of the region. In exchange, each one of the smaller Interpolating functions will be more accurate over its smaller region. So it is a trade off, but it worked very well for me.

Comment: Stopping the time of simulation to around 2.3 helped because the system has (almost) completed it's evolution by that time.

Using Method-> "StiffnessSwitching" prolongs the simulation all the way to around 2.37 but thats not much of an improvement for THIS problem. 

Thank you for your comments.

Also, what would anyone suggest if I run into a "no more memory available" problem?

Answer (score 3):

I you run into a "no more memory available" problem, the solution depends on what's causing the lack of memory. For example, I once had to run a simulation which required me to compute a 3D magnetic field over a large volume, as you might imagine, not only it took me a long time to compute it, but it also would be impractible to compute it everytime I had to run a simulation of the particles crossing it. To avoid memory problems and to make the program computationaly lighter, I decided to write the magnetic field data to a text file. A simple csv style of file with the B field vector for each point of space in a grid did the trick...

So, my advice is, in case you are running out of memory because you are computing huge amounts of data, you should stream it to a file and then read the file on the next step of the program... I hope this technique helps ;)

Comment: the other thing that seems to help (pl do correct me if I am wrong) that running mathematica as scripts instead of through the front end has eased the load on memory. I also think using a lot of grid points for simulations and plotting didn't help my case. It would seem that I am pushing `NDSolve` to its limit.